# Java, Evaluating Error

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error, evaluate

I am coding something. Then, Java is not evaluating it.

For example;

```
String[]names={"esma","meral","naci","derya","murat"};
System.out.println("Eleman sayısı:" names.length);
for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i+".eleman:"+names[i]);
}
```

I see this message on the left corner. "Evaluating..."

Yesterday, The program was worked by coding myself. But, Today, isn't working.

Comment: That doesn't compile without a `+` in the first `println` statement.

Comment: After sayisi:" it must be +names.length.

Answer (score 1):

The first `println` won't compile - you're missing a `+` sign after the first string:

```
System.out.println("Eleman sayısı:" + names.length);
// Here ----------------------------^
```